# A server side component for tracking a large number of RSS & Atom feeds

Tags: java, python, rss, atom-feed

I am looking for an open source component that can help me track a large number of [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) feeds (>> 10K RSS sources).

I don't care about the programming language, but it should be something with a simple API where I can add or remove RSS feeds and asynchronously receive notifications every time an RSS is updated.

Preferably in Java or Python.

Comment: Have you looked at http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this site.  Most of these seem to be client apps but some listed APIs.  Not sure if there's something here for you.  http://java-source.net/open-source/rss-rdf-tools